# Text to speech in a python node

Tags: ros, python, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've done the soundplay tutorial and can do text-to-speech from the command line, but can someone explain how to do it from inside a python program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10829/text-to-speech-in-a-python-node/) by [ringo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/651/ringo42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ringo,

The following works for me in Diamondback.

First add a dependency on sound_play to your package manifest.xml file:

```
<depend package="sound_play"/>
```

and re-run rosmake in your package directory.

Then launch the soundplay node from the command line or your launch file:

```
$ rosrun sound_play soundplay_node.py
```

or

```
<launch>
  <node name="soundplay_node" pkg="sound_play" type="soundplay_node.py"/>
</launch>
```

Finally, add the following Python snippets to your main speech script.

```
from sound_play.libsoundplay import SoundClient

self.soundhandle = SoundClient()
rospy.sleep(1)
self.soundhandle.say('Take me to your leader.')
```

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on 2015-09-21**:
I did this in hydro on a PR2. It worked without adding the dependency. Also, our PR2 automatically runs a soundplay node. If a second one is accidentally started, speech sounds choppy until the whole system is restarted (even restarting all ros processes doesn't fix it).